# Ordering BigQuery Results in Java SDK

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sdk

I am trying to get ordered results from a BigQuery with help of google cloud SDK.

The query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
            |WHERE id = 111
            |ORDER BY time DESC
```

Then I create and run the Job:

```
Job job = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query)
            .setUseLegacySql(false)
            .build()
```

The issue, is when I actually fetch results, I receive them unordered:

```
TableResult results = job.getQueryResults()
results.iterateAll()
```

If I run the original query inside the BigQuery UI, everything seems to fine.

Any ideas, at which place and why the results being shuffled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was, that I've added *ORDER BY* clause later in query.

Still, I was accessing the job with the same jobId.
That made BigQuery to fetch previous results, which where unsorted. 
Updating JobId helped!